# stimulating budding math kids? (8 yo)

Tags: reference-request, learning

My 8 yo child loves maths, he considers it "his hobby". Without pressuring him, I'd like to offer him more challenge, wonder and marvel. The school can't really offer him more (tables of multiplication, yay), and my clumsy attempts aren't helping.

I'm looking for resources/links/references I could use. A youtube maths for kids channel, or books or even a "mothly loot crate" subscription for maths?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**: the question got closed (not sure why), but I would like to thank every single person who commented and answered. You've really helped me here!
**Edit 2**: I've tagged this as a reference-request as per qwr's suggestion. I'd like to keep the question as new good ideas can keep pouring in forever (the boy is 9 now however ;-)

Comment: In my opinion, it can be challenging to get younger people interested in Mathematics, just because it "takes a while to get to the good stuff". Personally, I hated Mathematics as a child. Solving similar equations over and over again and doing times tables can definitely be boring, but it's unfortunately an important part of developing Mathematically. That being said, I'm sure there are lots of different motivating topics. I got really interested after hearing about Newton and how he invented Calculus and was adamant on learning it. Maybe historical stories like this would be interesting?

Comment: I feel your (and his) pain. I was also good at arithmetic when I was a child, and as a reward I had to sit in front of pages and pages of "hard sums" when everyone else was allowed to do fun things like measure circles and create tesselations and dissect triangles to work out their areas, and so on. Fortunately the need to train people up to be computers was passing, so I was (reluctantly for my teachers -- my schooling was oldfashioned) allowed eventually to do other things.

Comment: Depending on the inclination of the kid, it is easier to create more excitement about certain types of math than others. For example, with one of my daughters, solving "real world" data problems (collect the data, sort it, plot it, etc.) was a great way of teaching her about elementary statistics. With another daughter, drawing shapes/patterns with a geometry set as "art" was a way to get her excited about geometry. I don't have any references to point to - just sharing my personal experiece here.

Comment: The Beast Academy curriculum is by Art of Problem Solving, founded by Richard Rusczyk, a U.S. Math Olympiad winner. I believe the curriculum is designed to have challenging problems at all levels, starting at 2nd grade, and to teach the material at a deeper level. It doesn't have endless drills of the same question type. It's written as a comic book that my son enjoys reading. I think we paid about $100 for a yearly subscription to all of the online material for grades 2-5.

Comment: I think introducing your child to the KenKen puzzle could be good. Involves only extremely basic math (addition, subtraction, multiplication, division) but is also fun, and requires some creativity. I think also challenging your child to fill out a 3x3 magic square could also be fun for him.

Comment: [This page](https://www.homeschoolmath.net/online/favorite_puzzles.php) also contains some simple, but also rather subtle puzzles (though a few of them are not very good.)

Comment: I don't think the question should be closed as it is probably on-topic as a [tag:reference-request]

Answer (score 4):

Here are some math books my son has enjoyed:

1. Bedtime Math
2. The number devil
3. The boy who loved math
4. Number Crunch
5. Go Figure
6. Zero the hero
7. Wumbers

Also, we homeschool him and use "Beast Academy", which has an online curriculum for 2nd - 5th that I really like. It has some challenging problems, and some material not typically taught in elementary school in the U.S. It also has puzzles that my son likes.

Answer (score 2):

Some ideas:

1. Geometric building toys (zometool, polydron)
2. Do some basic computer programming
3. Experiment with a graphing calculator (desmos is great, but only 2d)
4. Books: Collections from Martin Gardner's Mathematical Games Column (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Gardner_bibliography#%22Mathematical_Games%22:_The_Scientific_American_columns)
5. The Sideways Arithmetic from Wayside School books: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sideways_Arithmetic_from_Wayside_School
6. Various pen-and-paper style puzzles can be found here: [https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/puzzles/](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/puzzles/)

Answer (score 1):

Here's some ideas I got from trying to get my sister interested in math:

1. Go for geometrical proofs to illustrate concepts. For example, we can prove that a tangent will be perpendicular to a circle by taking the limit as two points of secant coming close to each other. Well demonstrated by Eddie Woo [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rnit26oIxfQ).
2. Try for relatable problems like ones they can grasp through their experience. For example, they are $10$ people in a room, they all meet each other for the first time and want to give an introductory handshake, how many hand shakes occur?

Avoid using variables like $x$ or $y$, and entertain alternate solutions. For example, if you figure out two different ways to solve the above problem, you can figure out a closed form for sum of first n natural numbers.

A problem with this approach is that you have to find out good questions to ask.

3. If you are gonna give books (I found books ineffective in my experience), give ones with many pictures.
4. There is also this site called Art of Problem Solving. I have never used it myself but I know many friends who had been in that site from a young age and became very good at mathematics. I think the main focus of the site is about Olympiad problem solving.

Answer (score -1):

Not a really an answer to your question, but too long for a comment.

I would suggest that you try to widen the scope of his interest, especially more towards 'pure maths': the more abstract topics like set theory, algebra etc. I know - he's only 8 years old and all, and it may sound like absurdly complicated stuff, but I'm not talking about full-on, formal algebra or axiomatic set theory. There is a lot of very useful stuff to learn about the motivations for these things, which will help him when he later gets to the formal maths.

I remember around that age, I started having a real interest in knowing more about the background and playing around with the edges of the concepts I had learned in school, and I found it hugely frustrating that nobody else thought about these things.

For example, when we were doing endless calculations in school to learn long multiplication, I really wanted to know why it worked - there is a simple enough explanation for anyone who is motivated enough to learn; my guess is that your boy would like to explore that.

Or set theory - what is it actually for? This is actually one of the deepest and most fundamental subject in mathematics, and it is a very accessible subject for any child who is interested enough.